# how do you target everything but links?

Tags: jquery

In this scenario (your basic catalog), there are multiple `<div>`s, each containing an item photo and some text. The item photo is a link. One can click the photo, and the link takes you to that item ...

```
<div class="itembox">
    <a href="/100"><img src="item_100.jpg"></a>
    Item 100
</div>
<div class="itembox">
    <a href="/101"><img src="item_101.jpg"></a>
    Item 101
</div>
```

And consider this jquery:

```
$('.itembox').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $('a:first',this).attr('href');
});
```

With this, clicking "Item 100" will trigger the link. However, I don't want to interfere with the standard "click a link" behavior (when the image is clicked) because users ofter press modifier keys to open a page in a new tab, and each browser seems to handle javascript opened windows differently.

So... how does one open a window ONLY of the user clicks something that ISN'T a link? I'm going for something like this (which obviously doesn't work)...

```
$('.itembox').click(function(){
    if ($(this).not('a')) {
        window.location.href = $('a:first',this).attr('href');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's stopPropagation method, so that when a user clicks the real link, the click event doesn't reach the div.

Something like :

```
$('.itembox').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $('a:first',this).attr('href');
});

$('.itembox').find('a').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

That being said, if you're using an HTML5 Doctype, you could simply wrap you're whole "item" inside an `<a>` tag. No more need for javascript in this case. See reference here : http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

Comment: Ah! Yeah, how about that! Thanks for the double-solution :D

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery selector syntax provides for this:

```
$('.itembox :not(a)').click(...
```

see http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: This will actually look for "elements with the class 'itembox' that are not an a tag", wich isn't the problem here, as the a tag is a child of the 'itembox' element.

Comment: yeah, sadly doesn't do the trick .. if I change it to an alert, the alert is triggered when clicking the image link :P

Comment: I believe `$('.itembox').not('a').click(...` will also work but I'd have to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Either stop propagation, or try to get more accurate selections... Perhaps like this:

HTML

```
<div class="itembox">
    <a href="/100"><img src="item_100.jpg"></a>
    <span>Item 100</span>
</div>
<div class="itembox">
    <a href="/101"><img src="item_101.jpg"></a>
    <span>Item 101</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.itembox span').click(function() {
    // do stuff
}
```